# From Xcode Resource Deleting old images cause app crash in device randomly

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm facing very critical issue , I have deleted the unused  images from the Xcode resource. But it leads to crashes the App on device.  Not able to seen ant log ,Even Exception Break point can not  find it ,  Some time it show Logs "Could not load the "bu.png" image referenced from a nib" , Some time logs reproduced with another PNG name , I have deleted Lots of images from my Xcode resource.

Please Please  help me in this,

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you double check that images not into your project?

Comment: yes i Check , they where not in the project , But if search for them in code , It shows in then storyboard which is assign to a button of view controller , But no longer using the button , Final what i mean is a button with this image is set as background image , but not using it any where

Comment: what happen when you use into storyboard might be it creates the problem so if possible to remove from that images into it's relevant usage and clean the build and then try to check

Comment: How it now crash every time , 6 out 10 time app crashes  with this issue, There were so many screen and many removed images. So how can  resolve

Comment: It is working fine new , The check out i made to new MAC is not done properly  , This fixes the issue , Thanks for the Help @NimitParekh

Answer (score 0):

Delete app from device, clear Xcode build files (menu Build->Clean). Run app again.
This happens because when you delete images from Xcode it doesn't deleted from app on device.